# Splitting cell value and update existing columns

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

Just a short description about my problem.
I've two columns [`name`] and [`address`]
In one way or another the (partial)address is in the same cell as the name (imported form csv file).

I'd like to split the string in the name column (split on '2/') and add the address part to the column [`address`] and leave the name in the [`name`] column.
Just move it when [`address`] is empty and join if [`address`] is not empty.
Please find a sample below.

Raw data from csv:

```
name;address
Markus M Berg;Kirchenallee 52
Johanna P Wirth 2/Ufnau Strasse 48;
Felix B Beike 2/Mohrenstrasse 47;Dormettingen
```

Current situation

```
name                               | address
------------------------------------------------------------
Markus M Berg                      | Kirchenallee 52
Johanna P Wirth 2/Ufnau Strasse 48 |
Felix B Beike 2/Mohrenstrasse 47   | Dormettingen
```

Desired situation:

```
name                               | address
------------------------------------------------------------
Markus M Berg                      | Kirchenallee 52
Johanna P Wirth                    | Ufnau Strasse 48
Felix B Beike                      | Mohrenstrasse 47 Dormettingen
```

Comment: Do the cells have NaN or are they blank?

Comment: The cells are blank. As in the example

Comment: The issue is how you read the csv in pandas. Find out what delimiter is used to split data. Have you tried pd.read_csv('your_data.csv',sep='\t')? If you include dummy sample of raw data, we might be able to help!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Split on `r'\d/'` and reassign:

```
v = df.name.str.split(r'\d/', expand=True).fillna('')

df['name'] = v.iloc[:, 0].str.strip()
df['address'] = v.iloc[:, 1].str.cat(df['address'], sep=' ').str.strip()
```

```
print(df)
              name                        address
0    Markus M Berg                Kirchenallee 52
1  Johanna P Wirth               Ufnau Strasse 48
2    Felix B Beike  Mohrenstrasse 47 Dormettingen
```

Comment: I've a different result using your code. 0 and 2 are correct, but for 1 the name is correct `Johanna P Wirth` but address is `NaN`.

Comment: @JohnDoe That can only be possible if there are NaNs in the address column instead of blanks. That's why I asked you about that. Please fill the NaNs first, then run my code (use `df['address'] = df['address'].fillna('')`).